# Meteor Unit Testing with meteortesting:mocha

Tags: node.js, meteor, vulcanjs

I'm trying to add unit tests to my application. Currently I'm using
meteor 1.8.1, and meteortesting:mocha as test driver.

My issue is that when running a meteor test command the app seems not to load the helper files correctly
The test folder contains all test files is at root level so '/test/*.app-test-js'
and my helper is on '/packages/cms/lib/server/apis/ctRedsysSync'

and within the test file, I import my helper function to be tested

import {validateDate} from '/packages/cms/lib/server/apis/sync-helper';

but when running the test it throws an error saying the module is not found

I'm using  meteor test --full-app 3100 --driver-package meteortesting:mocha

So I was expecting all files to be loaded eagerly.

Sorry but at the moment I don't have a repo to share with the code, but I can provide more details if needed. I'd be really thankful if someone would help me understand what possible could be the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.